# Get file name and full link

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, administration, document

I have created a SharePoint to store about 800 files.

My problem is that I would like to generate a file list (txt or csv) which contains the file name and the link pointing to each file.

Is there a way to automatically do it?

Comment: Try using **[Export to Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9)** feature in SharePoint. After exporting the content in file, open it in "Excel" app and save it as a "CSV" file. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: HEllo Ganesh,I did not realize this feature was already there. Thanks so much have a nice day

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you Manu!

Comment: I have added this solution as an answer below. Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps for SharePoint Online Modern experience document library:

1. Go to your SharePoint Online Modern experience document library view
2. Click on **Export to Excel** option from top command bar:

   [image]
3. It will download a `.iqy` file, open it in Excel app on your desktop
4. Use "Save as" option and save it as a new CSV file.

**Documentation**: [Export to Excel from SharePoint or Microsoft Lists](https://support.microsoft.com/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9)

Answer (score 0):

You also could use PowerShell to get all file properties.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://wendytest123.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytestnew"
$ListName= "Documents"
$ReportOutput = "C:\DocInventory.csv"
$Pagesize = 5000
   
#Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Delete the Output report file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportOutput) { Remove-Item $ReportOutput}
 
#Array to store results
$Results = @()
   
#Get all Documents from the document library
$List  = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
$global:counter = 0;
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize $Pagesize -Fields Author, Editor, Created, File_x0020_Type -ScriptBlock `
        { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity `
             "Getting Documents from Library '$($List.Title)'" -Status "Getting Documents data $global:Counter of $($List.ItemCount)";} | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
  
$ItemCounter = 0
#Iterate through each item
Foreach ($Item in $ListItems)
{
        $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            Name              = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
            RelativeURL       = $Item["FileRef"]
            FileType          = $Item["File_x0020_Type"]
            RelativeURL       = $Item["FileRef"]
            CreatedByEmail    = $Item["Author"].Email
            CreatedOn         = $Item["Created"]
            Modified          = $Item["Modified"]
            ModifiedByEmail   = $Item["Editor"].Email
        })
    $ItemCounter++
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($ItemCounter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Exporting data from Documents $ItemCounter of $($List.ItemCount)" -Status "Exporting Data from Document '$($Item['FileLeafRef'])"        
}
  
#Export the results to CSV
$Results | Export-Csv -Path $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation
   
Write-host "Document Library Inventory Exported to CSV Successfully!"
```